# Cannot create facebook app - Stuck in verification

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create a test Facebook app using a new dev account I've created but I'm stuck at the verification step.

When I go to http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php, it keeps showing me this message:

[image]

I've done the mobile phone verification already. If i click on the *mobile phone* link it says it's already verified:

[image]

I've tried log out/in but it keeps coming up with this. It did once show me a page that looked like it was ok, but then reverted back at the next refresh.

Frustrating.

Any idea?

p.s. I don't particularly want to hand out my credit card and it says **or** so I assume both aren't needed, right?

Comment: If it's a new account dev-only account, I would just open a new one. With 500 mil users, there can be some glitches :)

Comment: I thought facebook was unbreakable? :)

Comment: You'll eat those words as soon as you begin your journey as a facebook developer :)

Comment: @Ben - I hear ya. I would just chuck the current account out the window and open a new one. Not worth the "debuging" efforts IMHO. Facebook understandably have no support. Imagine if 0.1% of their users had just one little question :)

Comment: OK... I have tried the procedure 3 times.. same result. Getting really frustrated now..

Comment: Apparently not alone.. http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16367.. vaguely re-insuring I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have faced some problems with user verification. You can follow these bugs through the Facebook Developer Bugzilla.  Here is the link to this bug exactly.

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15951

As you can see, there are another similar/duplicate bugs.